# Error when using URI.escape in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to simply escape an URL with spaces and then do a GET request to that URL in Ruby.

The error I have is

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:393:in `get_response': undefined method `host' for "http://google.com/?this%20is%20a%20stromg%20with%20spaces":String (NoMethodError)
from test_url.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

This is the current code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.escape("http://google.com/?this is a string with spaces")
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess) 

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

Comment: Doesn't the URI.escape method return a plain string? It seems you're passing an object to HTTP.start that does not have a host method/property. Have you tried passing uri instead of uri.host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`URI.escape` just escapes it, and nothing else. You need an actual instance of a `URI` to pass to `get_response`:

```
uri = URI.parse(URI.escape("http://google.com/?this is a string with spaces"))
```

Comment: escape still sees the url as `http://google.com/?this is a string with spaces`. Is there a way to escape replacing spaces with space characters so it can be valid in Ruby as URL?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow. Who 'sees' the url as a string with spaces? You call `URI.escape` (`URI.encode` should also work in this case, maybe try that) and pass the result to `URI.parse`.